# full screen zoom pan use UIScrollView in iphone

Tags: iphone, image, zooming, fullscreen, photo

I have follow a sample code, for create a simple image view zoom/pan page, but it will have the navigationController to back to main page. I have set the navigationBar to alpha to 0.3. But below the navigationBar, I can not see the image content. I have research the reseaon, the frame and bound is 320*480. Also in the xib file, change the "Status Bar" to None. It does not work.
How can I maek the image view full screen like the native photo app. THx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just provide a new tapguesture which provide user a facility to hide navigation bar and again on tap the bar is shown again

Comment: I have fixed this issue, set the barStyle to UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent. not set the alpha to bar.

Comment: thanks for accepting the answer and congratulation for the solution